# How to query data through fuzzy key in redis hash

Tags: java, hash, redis

I use redis hash to store my data. The key is a fixed value, the field stores "id" + "type" and the value stores the corresponding data. Is there anyway to query the data through a fuzzy key?

For example

The record is "ABC" : "12301" : "abc" and "ABC" : "12302" : "def", I want to use "ABC" + “123*”to query out the two records.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

You can use [`HSCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/hscan) with glob-like patterns, which appears to be what you need.

That said, scanning big Hashes can be time-consuming. Instead, you can build your own indices (see for example [Lexicographical Indexes](https://redis.io/topics/indexes#lexicographical-indexes) or use a search engine such as [RediSearch](https://redis.io/topics/indexes#lexicographical-indexes).